# Failing to login to MySQL using defaults-extra-file

Tags: mysql, docker

So I have MySQL hosted inside a docker container. I'm trying to write a bash script to extra some data from MySQL. I've created a file /etc/mysql_pass.cnf inside the docker container, the file contains:

```
[mysqld]
user=user1
password=pass2
```

My /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=XXXX
socket=XXXX
secure-file-priv=XXX
...etc
```

This is what i've written on the bash script to extract the result from MySQL:

```
mysqlDate=$(docker exec DOCKER_NAME mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql_pass.cnf -D$db -se "SQL_QUERY;")
```

I get this error
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
It's trying to login as root for some reason, and saying I haven't entered a password?